# tlmgr is not accessible after installing TeX Live 2011 on a Ubuntu system

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

> tlmgr -gui No command 'tlmgr' found, did you mean:
>   Command 'vlmgr' from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)  Command 'rlmgr'
>   from package 'qdbm-util' (universe) tlmgr: command not found

Since I downloaded TexLive 2011 from TUGs, shouldn't tlmgr be included?  If so, why can't I access it?

I'm on Xubuntu 11.04 64 bit.

Suggested solution did not appear to work:

```
peter@peter-xfce:~$ export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
peter@peter-xfce:~$ tlmgr --self --all update
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/texlive/tlnet
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2011/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
peter@peter-xfce:~$ sudo tlmgr --self --all update
[sudo] password for peter: 
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
peter@peter-xfce:~$ tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: missing action; try --help if you need it.
peter@peter-xfce:~$ tlmgr --help
You need to install the perl-doc package to use this program.
peter@peter-xfce:~$
```

Comment: Where did you install TeXLive? What's your current `$PATH`?

See http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Defaults, all defaults: /usr/local/texlive/2011

Comment: root has it's own path, so you need to make sure tlmgr is included in *root*'s path before `sudo tlmgr ...` will succeed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - does this mean I have two separate TextLive installations?  The path is where I installed it to right, /usr/local/texlive/2011 initially? Why should it be different for root versus user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

and then run `tlmgr --self --all update`. Does it work?

To set the path correctly with every login put the following as `zzz-texlive.sh` into `/etc/profile.d/`.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/`uname -i`-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
unset TEXINPUTS
unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

And you should always use `updmap-sys`, `fmtutil-sys`, if needed for installing additional fonts or creating new formats.

Comment: See above.  What appears to be the problem?

Comment: use `sudo tlmgr --self --all update`. You installed it as root, I personally prefer installing it as user. And, of course, have you installed perl? You also have to set the PATH variable as root

Comment: Yep, I saw that warning, but I repeated with sudo immediately after the warning.  It gave `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`.  Suggestions?

Comment: do it as root with `su <enter>`. Then set the path and run tlmgr. However, I would prefer the owner change of texlive: `sudo chown -R peter.users /usr/local/texlive` then you can do everything as user.

Comment: Presumably the installation couldn't have proceeded without perl?  I installed tk-perl.  perl I assumed was pre-installed cause the manual says it's default on Linux.  Also `sudo export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` gives
`sudo: export: command not found`

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't authorize me as su, but I did `sudo chown -R peter.users /usr/local/texlive` and repeated the actions, and all seemed in order.  Problem appears solved, but I still wonder if there was any reason why su was rejected, assuming I typed in my p.word correctly?

Comment: I suppose that Ubuntu doesn't allow `su`. But I am not sure, I am on SuSE. I'll update my answer in a couple of minutes to show, what you should do to set the path correctly at every system start.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I'm still not sure what "setting the path" refers to and why I'm having these problems.  Could you explain what this is all about?  Judging from your extended solution, would I expect this to be a recurring problem?

Comment: TeXLive does no changes to the system configuration and leaves all to the user. You can have several TeXLive installation on your system, eg 2010 and 2011. Resetting the path to another TeXLive Version is all what to do when switching to another TeXLive version.

Answer (score 16):

This will solve your problem:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --gui
```

> Basically, [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo) resets the value of `$PATH` (the whole environment,
>   indeed) to a "known good" one, and is thus ignoring any changes you
>   made to your local environment. The [env](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/env) command above sets the `PATH`
>   variable in the environment of the `tlmgr` it executes, so it runs with
>   the value of `$PATH` you specify on the command line.
>
> [Setting TeX Live path for root - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root)

Of course to get this working you'll have to add the TeX Live 2011 installation path to your `PATH` variable.

(For the GUI install the `perl-tk` package.)

Comment: This solution works fine for many linux distros. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, and the solution is slightly trickier than the above.

First, `su` works slightly differently in Ubuntu. As explained [in this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34329/su-command-authentication-failure), you need to call

> sudo su

Since root has its own path variable, you need to set your path variable. To do this, you need to include

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/

or its local equivalent in the `.bashrc`, which is located at `/root/`. To make the changes effective, save the file and run `source .bashrc &` in that terminal.

After that, you can start `tlmgr` in that terminal, as root, using

> tlmgr -gui

or you can run updates using

> tlmgr --self --all update

Answer (score 1):

```
$which latex
```

return for 32 bits

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/latex
```

or for 64 bits

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/latex
```

for update

```
$sudo /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr update --self
```

for full upgrade

```
$sudo /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr update --all
```

Comment: `which latex` returns `/usr/bin/latex` for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general question about how `sudo` is working.

Instead of setting environment variable `PATH`, you can run something like `sudo $(which tlmgr) update --self`. Be sure to check the path of `which tlmgr` is what you expected.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the differences in sudo and user PATH variable. In your case, you can either change the sudo safe path, which is not recommended, or just change the access of your Tex Live directory by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/texlive/
```

Then you can use the following command for installing your packages **without sudo**:

```
tlmgr install <package_name>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to give full read-write access to the TeX Live tree to any and all users. It is both unnecessary and may easily lead to trouble.

Comment: Reza, in thinking better here, the advice you give is quite dangerous. Picture the following scenario: You build your document and latex warns of an error in a package, you select the error and your editor opens the package file, you inadvertently type something in the file, you try to build again and your editor saves all files. And, there you go, you have broken installation. I appreciate your will to participate, and I wish I could be more welcoming. But I'll have to flag your answer for moderation attention.

Comment: Btw, I also strongly recommend you don't use this yourself.

Comment: Well, although you are correct about the safety of doing my way, but some of mentioned ways is more dangerous than my way and you can think of lots of ways to do something wrong with for example changing sudo safe path! But in my case, the only possibility is to broke a package or broke the whole installation. In addition, every  linux user, should be careful about the power of sudo command and giving an access to a file. Power brings responsibilities :)