# I have a problem with installing tlmgr

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tlmgr is not accessible after installing TeX Live 2011 on a Ubuntu system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-is-not-accessible-after-installing-tex-live-2011-on-a-ubuntu-system)

My computer runs on Fedora 15 x86-64. I installed TeX Live using my package manager, but couldn't run `tlmgr`. So I downloaded the TeX Live installation file form [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html), and still couldn't run `tlmgr` (after downloading 2400 packages for TL through it's installation file). Why is that happening?

Comment: When you [download TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and [follow the installation instructions](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), it should automatically install `tlmgr`. Is this what you did? It seems like you went through all the trouble of downloading TL without properly installing it.

Comment: Yes, I read and did exactly what that page says.

Comment: Does [`tlmgr` is not accessible after installing TeX Live 2011 on a Ubuntu system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26624/5764) help? You may have to set the appropriate path.

Comment: @Werner Oops, I missed the path setting part, it actually worked. Thanks. I don't have enough reputation to answer the question, could you please do that?

Comment: I've added an answer, but will vote to close this question since it is solved by another.

Comment: Clearly the same issue => duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set/add the path to your TeX Live binaries using:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin:$PATH
```

And if you're using a 64 bit installation it may be:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```