# Install texlive

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

I am trying to install texlive in order to recover files swept away in the process of installing another latex software package.

The basic problem is that I want to run `tlmgr` to recover lost packages, but the command line does not recognize this command.

Now, I am pretty sure I installed texlive before, but I can't be certain. 
A `locate` search turns up many results, the most numerous being in a folder called "textmf-texlive."

I am following the installation process on this page: http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html
I am running this perl script:

`install-tl-20130114`

It says on the page that I should remove previous installation.
But I don't see any files like the ones on the page.
I see only the previously mentioned "textmf-texlive" folder, which I am not certain that it has anything to do with actual texlive, especially since `tlmgr` will not run.
So I think I can just go ahead and run the script.

At the end of this page it says I have to set a PATH.
This I am sure I did not do, which might be the reason `tlmgr` does not work.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. After I run the installer, can I just copy and paste the code on the web page to set the PATH?

### Edit

People might also want to have a look at the question (and the according detailed answer) [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/25077)

Comment: it is easier to just use apt to install it. Or the synaptic GUI manager.

Comment: When I do that it just goes to the 2009 version in the repositories. They haven't updated it in years. How would I apt-get the latest version?

Comment: I just installed texlive on linux mint, it is using the latest verion: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian). Used the GUI manager. One click is all took. May be you are using an old repository?  I used the default repository for linux mint 14. See if you can find a deb based repository that is newer, or search for the .deb file itself on the net. It is there somewhere, since I just installed it (mint uses apt like debian, so the .deb file should work)

Comment: @ Nasser Sorry for making a long comment, but...so I just type `sudo apt-get install pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13`? And pdfTeX includes/is the same as TeX Live?

Comment: You should use `texlive` as the name of the package. It will include everything. Use the command `apt search texlive` to see.

Comment: But that is what I am saying, I type `sudo apt-get install texlive` and it goes right to the 2009 repository

Comment: As I said, in that case, need to find a repository for your debian that has a later texlive .deb package, or search the net for the .deb file itself and download it, and double click on it to install. sorry, not on debian myself. I use linux mint.

Comment: There are debian repositories that have 2012 textlive, here there are: http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html  if you use the GUI interface to apt (synaptic) then it is easy to add a repository there.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-is-not-accessible-after-installing-tex-live-2011-on-a-ubuntu-system/26626#26626

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have some troubles with the concept of `$PATH` etc, you will be much better off by using the Ubuntu packages; see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/163682/62688) and its answers.