# pst-3dplot error with IIIDlabels

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I have encountered a problem with my `pst3dplot`. With the option `IIIDlabels` enabled I end up with lots of black spikes instead of labels on the coord axes. Without `IIIDlabels` the `pst-3dplot` works fine.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{xetex-pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
%\psset{coorType=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.5)(5,5)
\pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=black,IIIDticks,IIIDlabels,xMin=-2,yMin=-2,zMin=-2]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

---

I am running this code on a linux machine: Xubuntu 15.04 with TeXlive 2015 and `xelatex` (with the same problem under 14.04 and 14.10). The problem occurrs independent of the psset coord 2 setting. Including the package `xetex-pstricks` results in an error, but without explicitly loading it the console output tells me it is loading the package anyway -- and without errors.

How do i get rid of the spikes? How do I put the correct labels there instead?

Any suggestions are welcome, thx in advance!

The result of a run with \listfiles is:

```
 *File List*
 standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
 ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
 class
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
 size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
 pstricks.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 pst-fp.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PST-fp' (hv)
 xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 xetex.def    2015/03/25 v4.04 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
 e/RRM/JK)
 pst-3dplot.sty    2010/01/01 package wrapper for pst-3dplot.tex (hv)
 pst-3d.sty    2009/07/28 package wrapper for pst-3d.tex (hv)
 pst-3d.tex    2010/02/14 v1.11 `PST-3d' (hv)
 pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
 pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
 multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
 multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
 pst-plot.tex    2014/08/23 1.70 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
 pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
 pst-node.tex    2014/08/04 1.35 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
 pst-3dplot.tex    2014/08/25 v2.01 `PST-3dplot' (hv)
 ***********
```

Updating the TeXLive version to 2015 help to produce the following output. The stripes have disappeared and the IIIDlabels are put at the correct positions. The rotation of the numbers is, however, still missing.

[image: TeXLive 2015 output]

Comment: How come there have not been any answers to my question yet? Is it obvious what my mistake is? I still have not figured out how to get rid of the spikes, so any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: I cannot see it with an up-to-date TeXLive

Comment: It appears to me that the problem comes from the pstplaneput function. One reason for this guess is that everything works fine without IIIDlabels, the other reason is that pstplaneput fails on my system when running xelatex ([see this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246486/pst-3dplot-error-transformation-matrix-not-invertible?noredirect=1#comment600195_246486))

Comment: The thing is that I don't need the plane rotations when adding the labels to the ticks. Non-rotated upright fonts should do fine for my purposes. So I have been thinking to rewrite the 'if IIIDlabels' part of pst-3dplot, but failed so far. The code I want to edit is:
\ifPst@IIIDlabels%
            \pstPlanePut[plane=\psk@IIIDxTicksPlane](\rB,\pst@tempE,\pst@OffsetZ){%
              \psxyzlabel{\expandafter\@LabelComma\nA..\@nil\psk@xlabelFactor}}%
%              \psxyzlabel{\nA\psk@xlabelFactor}}%
          \fi%
so that it will simply put the numbers there instead of rotating them first

Comment: put `\listfiles` into your preamble and post the file list which can be found at the end of your logfile.

Comment: have added the list in the question

Comment: that cannot be TL 2015. Nearly all PSTricks files are not up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks, @Herbert , for your advice: Updating TeXLive outside the repo did the trick. I used the script described
[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114623/installing-texlive-on-ubuntu-revisited).
I now get numbers at the ticks of the coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `xelatex` the labels are not placed as 3d objects. Looks like a bug with the xdvipdfmx driver. Hower, running `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` will work:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    %\psset{coorType=2}
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.5)(5,5)
    \pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=black,IIIDticks,IIIDlabels,xMin=-2,yMin=-2,zMin=-2]
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]