# pst-3dplot error: Transformation matrix not invertible

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I'm trying to reproduce example 1 on page 26 of the user manual of pst-3dplot. It is supposed to rotate the label 'xy plane' into a 3D coordinate system.

All I get is a warning:

```
** WARNING ** Transformation matrix not invertible.
** WARNING ** --- M = [-154.772 0 0 0 6447.73 -40.3858]
```

and no rotation. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(3,4)
\psset{Alpha=30}
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-4,yMin=-4,zMin=-4]
\pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,-3){\fbox{\Huge\red xy plane}}
%\pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,0){\fbox{\Huge\red xy plane}}
%\pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,3){\fbox{\Huge\red xy plane}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't confirm, maybe your package is old?

Comment: might be. I have updated pst-3dplot and multido, but problem is still present. btw I run this on TeXlive 2014, but updating to 2015 did not solve the problem either.

Comment: I have no problem with current TeXLive and GhostScript version 9.15

Comment: Thank you, Herbert, for picking up the problem. I also have no problem with current TeXLive and gv running latex and opening the dvi.
It fails, however, with xelatex to produce a pdf

Comment: As @Herbert has pointed out, the xelatex driver seems not to be working correctly. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244718/pst-3dplot-error-with-iiidlabels/252700#252700)