# texlive-full and xzdec installed, but tlmgr not working

Tags: debian, tlmgr

I followed the instructions of the accepted answer of
https://askubuntu.com/questions/485514/how-to-properly-install-and-use-texlive-with-package-manager-in-14-04

but when I try to install any new package, I get

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5579.
```

This is starting to be very frustrating.
Can somebody kindly guide me? Thank you

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to install manually following

[How can I manually install a LaTeX package (Debian/Ubuntu Linux)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux)

so I downloaded the package from CTNA (aastex.zip, which btw is alread contained in Tex Live, according to CTAN repo) unpacked it and moved the content to `/usr/share/tex-common`

I then tried calling `latex` with either of the (seemingly relevant) files: `aastex6.cls` and `aasjournal.bst`, but in both cases I get

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `aastex6.log'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.log')
Please type another transcript file name:
```

My first guess is that I should not do this last call. If so, what should I do?

Then, one thing that strikes me is the `TeX Live 2013/Debian`, but this is latex  which resulted on my machine from the installation procedure linked in the 'how to install the "vanilla" TexLive' (http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)

Can somebody see through this? Thank you again

Comment: You are using a TeX Live before 2016. The official TeX Live repository currently does only support TeX Live 2016. You cannot use `tlmgr` of TeX Live before 2016 with a current repository. You may install either Vanilla TeX Live 2016 or TeX Live 2017 prerelease parallel to your outdated TeX Live. See also [scottkosty's answer to "Installing TeXlive on Ubuntu, revisited"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171560/9057).

Comment: Maybe also interesting: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: I looked at the link and I discovered I already did it a while ago (back then to convert jupyter notebooks into latex). Important info I forgot to mention: I'm using Kile on Ubuntu 14. I will just figure out how to install the package manually and end of the story

Comment: You are not using Vanilla TeX Live but TeX Live from debian linux. Maybe you missed setting `PATH` so still the TeX binaries from the installed debian packages are used. For correct installation of Vanilla TeX Live see the link in my second comment.

Comment: Calling LaTeX for a file with extension `.cls` or `.bst` is mostly wrong. Is `/usr/share/tex-common` a valid local TDS tree on your system? You can test this, e.g., using `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`.

Comment: running this command returns */usr/local/share/texmf*. In this folder there's also the **ls-R** (which showed up in <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux>). I guess I should copy the sty file in one of the subfolders in this directory, find its location in the **ls-R** file and add a line with the name of the new package. Right? Is there a specific subfoder or I can choose any one?  

I will also try to install the Vanilla Tex Live

Comment: `ls-R` should be updated using `texhash` (see also [`kpathsea.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/kpathsea/kpathsea.pdf)). For more information about how to place a file in a TDS tree read [`tds.pdf`](http://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf).

Comment: I installed TexLive following the indications at the page you linked. I got the following error at the end, when running `sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2016-2_all.deb` I got                   `dpkg: regarding texlive-local_2016-2_all.deb containing texlive-local:
 texlive-base conflicts with texlive-common
  texlive-local provides texlive-common and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive texlive-local_2016-2_all.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing texlive-local
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-local_2016-2_all.deb`
Any idea how to solve

Comment: I've linked different pages. Nevertheless, I you create a dummy package you should deinstall the already installed `texlive-*` packages of your linux distributions before.

Comment: I've installed the vanilla texlive from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171560/9057>. if I do `which tlmgr` I get `/opt/texbin/tlmg` and when I do `sudo tlmgr install asstex` (with the sudo necessary because I got `You don't have permission to...`), I get again then same error: `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5579.` Clues?