# Is there a reliable guide for installing non-apt TeX Live on Ubuntu, detailing different procedures for global vs user installations?

Tags: installing, ubuntu

The TeX distribution provided by `apt` on Ubuntu is not the latest (2023 at the time of this question). So one may want to install directly from [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive).

At this point an important choice is whether one wants to install the distribution for just a single user, or globally in the system so that all existing and future users can access it.

The official [Guide](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) does a great job of explaining everything. However when it comes to the question of *system-wide* installation vs *single-user* installation, it says:

> If you want to make these changes globally, or for a user newly added to the system, then you are on your own; there is just too much variation between systems in how and where these things are conﬁgured.

Fair enough.

Doubts appear already when running the first install command: should one run

```
perl ./install-tl
```

or

```
sudo perl ./install-tl
```

?

Thereafter comes all the complicated (for a low-level user like me) situation of configuring `PATH`s and so on.

TeX and AskUbuntu have plenty of scattered questions related to this, but often they give different solutions (or at least they look different to a low-level user), and many are a few years old, and I'm unsure whether they still apply or not.

So I wonder if you can forward me to a *reliable* guide that addresses these points in a systematic manner, for Ubuntu and derivates.

I'm really lost with all options and contradicting instructions and warnings scattered a bit everywhere :(

Comment: Would this https://askubuntu.com/a/1228573/16395 helps? I am doing this since 3-4 years (installing a minimal apt-based texlive, and then using a personal/portable one).

Comment: Thank you @Rmano The procedure there is useful for a personal/portable installation, but I would like to have an updated, system-wide one.

Comment: Ah, I never did one of that, sorry. But I imagine that this is the same, just: use `sudo` to install in  some system directory (like `/usr/local/texlive` or similar), and *not* choose a portable installation. Notice however that in Ubuntu, from my experience, you *need* a minimal `apt` installation or you'll have a dependency hell...

Comment: @Rmano that is what I did, but then questions remain: do I have to change other things as `sudo`? For example, some answers here speak of running `sudo visudo` or similar things. What you say about the apt installation is frightening. Again I think there's need of a reliable guide out there.

Comment: well, it depends. If you want all user by default using the new installation, you should add it *before the apt one* in some global environment file that sets up the path for any user (shell dependent, I think, like `/etc/profile.d/...`). I think that asking a specific question about what isn't working would be more useful.  You can also look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24937/how-do-i-set-path-variables-for-all-users-on-a-server

Comment: About `sudo visudo`: this is for giving a normal user the right to run things as root. Maybe to allow them to run `tlmgr`? I would really *not* do that. If the installation is system-wide, the system administrator should be the one doing this kind of things. This is why in my machine I prefer using a portable installation.

Comment: @Rmano You see the problem there: what if it's necessary to do something that one (a low-level user) has not even thought about? I can't ask questions about details that I don't even know the existence of... Also, many questions and answers are a bit old, and I always wonder if they're still valid.

Comment: @Rmano I appreciate your concern and thank you for the warning. This is exactly why I'm asking about a *reliable* guide. I'm really lost with all options and contradicting instructions and warnings scattered a bit everywhere :(

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9044/1090

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. Just upvoted that meta-question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171560/277964

Comment: @cabohah The guide you mention is for TeX Live 2016?

Comment: @pglpm 2023, 2016, 1999, .. issues are identical apart from the year

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is: how can a low-level user know that? Some answers seem to depend on the year and they are contradictory. One of the linked guides uses `sudo ./install-tl`. But then a comment says "that's not recommended. You should change ownership of etc/local/... instead". For setting PATH variables, one answer says to modify something in `/etc/profile`; but then another says no, the relevant directory has changed. Another answer says to use `sudo visudo`, but a comment above says that's dangerous... Sorry for the lack of links, I've been roaming here for 6 hours today.

Comment: @pglpm issues around root and sudo are not specific to texlive and or even linux, you would have had the same issues (or I would, at least) installing tex in sun bsd unix in 1989

Comment: @pglpm If users follow the link to scott's github repository there, they will find, that the last update has happened in April. And the README.md also states: “installs the latest version of TeX Live”. So yes, you should expect, that it works for the latest TeX Live.

Comment: in particular if you give yourself sudo access then you have write access to (and for instance could accidentally delete) every file on the machine. Some tutorials may describe that as "dangerous" some may just consider it as natural for installing any software for all users. So having it described as dangerous or not is not "contradictory" and not about tex; just about linux system management and being careful with super user access

Comment: @cabohah Nope. I checked the Readme of the repo, it says "Installs the latest version of TeX Live (as of writing, TeX Live 2019)". Some files might have been changed two months ago, but the changes could be just correction of a typo. I don't "expect" anything when contradictory information is given.

Comment: @pglpm “as of writing” means, when the `README.md` has been written, not when the latest update has been written. And ”latest version” indeed means latest version. Try it Thomas, try it … But, because of your problems in believing, I've also added an [issue](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/issues/42). I hope, the three year numbers will be removed from the README.

Comment: @cabohah I understand your point of view, but I've been in similar situations (repos with recently updated files, Readme not updated) when things didn't work instead – and the reply then was "but didn't you read the Readme? we stopped updating this a while ago, we're just doing small bug corrections for the old versions". Unfortunately different developers think differently and mean things differently, and I can't just read their minds :/
Consider also that that repo's script uses `sudo`, so one wants to be extra careful.

Comment: @pglpm As I told already two times: The README already says: “latest version” and currently the latest version is TeX Live 2023. The README also says, that TeX Live 2019 was the latest version, when the README has been written. And yes the script uses `sudo` as you would have to using `apt`, because they do something similar.

Comment: @pglpm [README.md](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu#readme) does not refer to old TeX Live releases any longer. So your problem with interpreting it different should be solved. Thanks to scott for changing it!