# Tex Live installation, and a problem of getting evince to show dvi files

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

As the picture shown, the left top picture shows that I have installed Tex Live successfully, but when I input the code 'latex', it shows that I have not installed the latex program and recommends me use the code (the Chinese characters on the picture means that) 'sudo apt install texlive-latex-base', which is shown in the right bottom picture! I wonder why. I installed Tex Live but there is no latex program in my computer

I installed Tex Live according to link

I am beginner of latex, and I'm sorry for ask trival a so simple question.[image]

Comment: In the top left corner terminal, two lines before the end of the install, it is said *"Most importantly, add <path> to your PATH for current and future session"*. It means, that binaries are well installed, but your system doesn't know where to look for them, and thus 'thinks' you have not installed it (and recommend you a way to do it).

Comment: the message at the top line of the right hand box is telling you to set your PATH (in .profile or similar startup file) to include the 2016 bin directory, have you done that?

Comment: Did you do what the last line of the installation output say, namely `Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux to your PATH for current and future sessions`?

Comment: Please post the results of `echo $PATH` after you have done what gemot asked (remember, it might be a good idea to log out and in again)

Comment: Thank you, after doing  that, the PATH is okay, and latex can compile .tex code. thank you!

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26624/5763

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the lines

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

to `$HOME/.profile`. As a user of `bash` I also have the line

```
source ~/.profile
```

in `$HOME/.bashrc`.

In order for the change to affect not only newly started shells, but also programs managed by the GUI, you have to start a new session.

---

### Problems with evince and a local TeXLive installation under Ubuntu

(This addresses an issue raised in the comments below the answer.)

The document viewer Evince may exhibit two problems when trying to view dvi files in this arrangement.

**Evince fails to display dvi files.** When starting it from the command line, you see messages like

> ```
> kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+100/600 --dpi 700 cmss12
> mktexpk: Permission denied
> ```

Evince is supervised by apparmor, a kernel module for preventing applications from doing mischief, and is forbidden to use TeXLive in `\usr\local`. You can either switch off supervision completely by

```
sudo aa-disable /usr/bin/evince
```

(`aa-disable` comes with the `apparmor-utils` package), or you modify the apparmor rules. Add the following lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/evince`:

```
# TeXlive 2016
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexpk Cx -> sanitized_helper,
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/mktextfm Cx -> sanitized_helper,
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/dvipdfm Cx -> sanitized_helper,
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/mkofm Cx -> sanitized_helper,
/usr/local/texlive/** r,
```

and the following lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers`:

```
# TeXlive 2016
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf{,-dist}/web2c/{,**/}* Pixr,
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/* Pixr,
```

Insert the lines near similar-looking rules for Ubuntu-TeX. For these changes to take effect without rebooting, issue the command

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

**Evince re-generates fonts each time a dvi file is viewed.** When starting it from the command line, you see messages like

> ```
> kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+100/600 --dpi 700 cmss12
> mktexpk: /home/someuser/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmss12.700pk already exists.
> ```

This is caused by Evince not finding the new configuration file for TeXLive 2016. The problem can be solved by putting a link to it into the folder `/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c`:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

**Tested for**

- TeXLive 2016, Ubuntu 16.04, evince 3.18.2
- TeXLive 2016, Ubuntu 16.10, evince 3.22

Comment: Very thankful for your answer, but after doing as you said, the problem remains as before. I run the command 'latex test.tex' to compile a test code and it shows that: latex program has not been installed.

Comment: @Zhang First, try the command `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/latex`, to make sure that `latex` indeed exists in the directory. Then issue `echo $PATH` on the command line; this gives a list of directories, among them there should be `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux`. If this is the case, `latex` on the command line should work.

Comment: Thank you! 'path+latex' works while 'latex' does not, this kind of problem may be caused by the 'PATH variable'. But I added export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
these three line to the file $home/.profile

Comment: also it does not work. Is it that the Path variable adding not successfully?

Comment: Which shell do you use? Each shell has rules, which initialisation files are loaded depending whether it is used interactively or non-interactively, whether as login-shell or not. For `bash`, you also have to modify `.bashrc`, see above. What do you get when issuing `echo $SHELL` on the command line?

Comment: I use CLI shell. The second file has also been modified(adding 'source ~/.profile in the last line?'). Run "echo %PATH" it doesn't echo any path related texlive.  Is there any other method to add PATH variable?

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` say?

Comment: /home/zhangli/bin:/home/zhangli/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
add three lines the end of file ~.profile , and

Comment: @Zhang What is the output of `echo $SHELL` (**not** `echo $PATH`)?

Comment: and one line to ~.bashrc. the result is as above. But if I add three lines to ~.bashrc, the 'echo $PATH' results contains the texlive path, then 'pdflatex, xelatex' can compile .tex code and the .pdf  document can be opened easily while 'latex' compile .tex code and the .dvi document can't be open by evince. Two questions: 1,the methods of the two differs? 2, add three lines to ~.bashrc can modify the variable path but the .dvi document can't be opened, this problem is related to the second method? Is the method wrong?

Comment: Yeah, 'echo $SHELL' echoes '/bin/bash'

Comment: @Zhang Have you logged out and started a new session?

Comment: yeah, I modify the file and close the terminal and start a new one, othewise the new path will not echo

Comment: @Zhang Not just a new terminal, but quit the GUI session and login in again. Programs started from the GUI see the environment as it was when the GUI was started.

Comment: yeah, I reboot the computer and the path is OK! Thank you! But I would like to ask if you know what's the problem results in that the .dvi document can't be opened?

Comment: @Zhang Open a terminal and start `evince yourfile.dvi` from there. Do you get error messages in the terminal window? `evince` may have problems to generate the fonts.

Comment: yean,  the error massage is too much, how I show you the picture?/home/zhangli/图片/compile.png

Comment: @Zhang Try to view the dvi file with `xdvi` (an old program included in texlive) and with `okular` (a modern document viewer included in Ubuntu that you might have to install first). Does this work? Regarding the error messages, maybe just show the first few lines.

Comment: xdvi works well, but there is no okular in my system. I'm downloading

Comment: the error massage is :kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmmib10
mktexpk: 权限不够
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
page: Warning: font `cmmib10' at 600x600 not found, trying `cmr10' instead

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktexpk: 权限不够
page: Warning: font `cmmib10' not found, trying metric files instead
 the Chinese character means that I don't have the power

Comment: okular also can open .dvi,  but when it is running some errors also occur. But these errors doesn't influence reading the document.

Comment: Before,  I use 'sudo apt-get install texlive-full' to install latex, and use 'latex' to compile .tex code, then evince .dvi works well

Comment: @Zhang The problem is that evince uses app-armor, a mechanism strictly controlling what evince is allowed to do. In the new texlive installation, newly generated fonts are written below `$HOME/.texlive2016`, and it seems that evince is not allowed to do that. So you have either to allow evince to generate the fonts or change the path where the TeX tools put the fonts.

Comment: I want evince to generate the fonts, but how could I do that?

Comment: @Zhang I will try to resolve this problem regarding evince. In the meantime, either use `pdflatex` or `xelatex` to generate `pdf` files and view them with `evince` (or any other pdf viewer, but evince is able to show pdf files), or use `latex` and use another `dvi` viewer like `okular`.

Comment: @Zhang I think I have solved your evince problem; see my extended answer.

Comment: @ Very thanks for your answer. I use the third solution to solve my evince problem, but there is no a file 'ubuntu-helper' under the path '/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions', if I should make a new file? A nother qusetion, how do I star a chat with somebody, the comment items are so many here.

Comment: @Zhang I've created a new chatroom, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47158/texlive-installation-ubuntu Please join to continue the conversation there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to talk, would like to continue here?

Comment: @Zhang Which Ubuntu version and which evince version do you use? Which output do you get from the command `sudo egrep -l 'texmf|mktexpk' /etc/apparmor.d/*{,/*} 2>/dev/null` ? This is *one* command in *one* line. It lists the files in `/etc/apparmor.d` and its subdirectories that contain either `texmf` or `mktexpk`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Chat would be a great idea (and Stackexchange probably would have suggested it already automatically) if there weren't a reputation limit for chatting. Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you so late for my net problems. The ubuntu version I use is 16.04, and the evince version is 3.18.2.  I use the following two commands `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c` and 
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` later to fix my problem, when it was done, I use evince to open .dvi files, it shows that the file texmf.cof does not have enough authority

Comment: @Zhang Have you noticed the line `/usr/local/texlive/** r,` in the file `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/evince` (see above)? I added it in a later update, together with the `mkdir` and `ln -s` commands.

Comment: I'm sorry I have done all things you said, but the problem remains still. I added the six lines to the bottom of the file `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/evince` and added the three lines to the file `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers`, but I don't know where to insert the two lines in the file. I tried to insert the bottom and 66th line, and I reboot the apparmor, and then I used command` `sudo mkdir -p /...` and `sudo ln -s /...`, all was done, but the problem remains still. Maybe the location I chose to insert the three line to `ubuntu-helpers` was wrong?

Comment: @Zhang If you mean with "at the bottom" literally at the bottom, then this will be wrong for `ubuntu-helpers`, since it is terminated by `}`, and the lines have to be added before. Best insert the lines near the lines for Ubuntu texlive (search for `texmf` or `texlive`). Just to make sure: did you restart apparmor after these changes?

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is solved, and main cause was that the `}` terminated the three lines in file `ubuntu-helpers`. Now evince can view dvi files without any problem. Thank you!